# Using rails before_action if it is only executed in certain cases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

the following is my code for one of my controllers I have written for my Rails show reviewing application. Note that I that I did not use Devise for user auth.
The problem I am facing right now is that I want the user (pco) to only be able to update the show if he/she is the one which originally uploaded it. Here, `authorized_as_pco_to_show` can determine that but it needs the `@show` to be passed into it as a parameter. Therefore, I cannot use `before_action`.

The way I have it right now is to put this `authorized_as_pco_to_show` method at the start of every action which only allows for the correct pco to access it. I was wondering if there would be a better way of doing this. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
  def update
    authorized_as_pco_to_show @show
    
    respond_to do |format|
      if @show.update(show_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @show, notice: "Show was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @show }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @show.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Where does `@show` come from? You can use it in a `before_action` if you slot it in after that's populated. It's all about ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass parameters to before actions if required. Instead of this:

```
before_action :authorized_as_pco_to_show
```

You can use:

```
before_action do
  authorized_as_pco_to_show @show
end
```

However, as mentioned in the comments, you'll need to get that show from somewhere. Assuming you have another before_action along the lines of `load_show` which loads it into an instance variable, you can then just use that within your other before_action. Something like this:

```
before_action :load_show, :authorized_as_pco_to_show

# your actions here

private

def load_show
  @show = Show.find(params[:id])
end

def authorized_as_pco_to_show
  @show.authorized? # replace with whatever your checks are
end
```